# C - Generate warning when loosely defined function is called

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

I'd like to generate a compiler warning for a specific situation. I'm building a sort of universal code that will be built based on several pre-compiler definitions. For instance I might have something like the following.

---

**sdcard.h**

```
#ifdef PART_BOARD1
    #include "port/board1.h"
#elif PART_BOARD2
    #include "port/board2.h"
#endif

extern void sdcardConfigure(void);
```

**sdcard.c**

```
#ifndef FLAG_SDCARD
    #warning "No SD Card available for this board, or this board has not been defined"
    #define sdcardConfigure(...) void(0)
#endif
```

---

**port/board1.h (similar for port/board2)**

```
#define FLAG_SDCARD
void sdcardConfigure(void);
```

**port/board1.c**

```
void sdcardConfigure(void) {
    // sd card is configured here
}
```

---

Essentially what I'd like to do is modify the `#define sdcardConfigure(...)` statement in `sdcard.c` so that I'm only seeing the warning message if `sdcardConfigure()` is actually called. Making it act like:

```
void sdcardConfigure(void) {
    #warning "sdcardConfigure() not available on this board"
}
```

The idea being that this gives me the flexibility to create a universal (I know many fear universal) program that adapts to the parts that it's using. I.E. if there is an SD Card use it, otherwise generate a warning saying "you're calling a function that doesn't exist for this part" and let the developer decide if the function is needed.

Comment: gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

Comment: OK - see answer below - I've also added a `gcc` tag to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this will most-likely be compiler-dependent.

For gcc et al you can use `__attribute__ ((deprecated))` ([see gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)).

For Visual Studio you can use `__declspec(deprecated)`.

Comment: Thanks. The 'deprecated' caught me off guard, I thought `__attribute__` had been deprecated but it is the deprecated `__attribute__`.
What I have now is `void sdcardConfigure(void) __attribute__((deprecated("sdcardConfigure unavailable")));` as the declaration (if FLAG_SDCARD isn't supplied). This basically does exactly what I wanted. The only issue being that the warning message is a bit confusing since the function isn't actually being phased out.

Comment: Yes, it's not quite ideal - it's a pity that you can't add a suitable message to the deprecated warning - but I think it's probably the best you can do as far as warning only if a call to the function is compiled.